# Always creating instance of class?

Tags: c++

I have a class that has only one function "Print()" and two properties "age, sex". And i am trying to understand when is object creating on memory?

i can always access to object's props and functions even i didn't call it's constructor function.

Isn't there any rule for the creating object from the class?

In C# this won't create object on memory: `ClassName cls;`
But this will create: `ClassName cls = new ClassName();`
**In C++ is there any way to not create object in memory until i need to call it's constructor function?**

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

class ClassName{
public:
    void print(){
        cout<< "Age: " <<age <<endl;
        cout<< "Sex: " <<sex <<endl;
    }
    int age;
    char sex;


};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    ClassName *ex1 = new ClassName();
    ex1->print();

    ClassName ex2;
    ex2.print();

    ClassName ex3= {10,'e'};
    ex3.print();

    ClassName exCopy(ex3);
    exCopy.print();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking why the four different methods you've posted all result in valid objects when you haven't explicitly defined any constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In C# this willn't create object on memory: ClassName cls; But this will create: ClassName cls = new ClassName(); In C++ is there any way to not create object in memory until i need to call it's constructor function?

The equivalent to your C# example, using C++, is as follows:

```
//pointer to ClassName, not initialized
ClassName* cls1;
//alternatively
ClassName* cls2 = 0;
//initialize after declaring it but before using it
cls1 = new ClassName();
cls1->print();
//after initializing it, don't forget to delete it again later
delete cls1;
cls1 = 0;
//this is an error (using uninitialized pointer)
cls2->print();
```

C# classes are 'reference' types, which are like C++ 'pointer' types.

Comment: This is very good point: "C# classes are 'reference' types, which are like C++ 'pointer' types."

Comment: -1: This is actually not the equivalent to a C# reference. A C# reference is managed by the garbage collector, which is not the case here. The application has to manage the memory on it's own (as @Neils answer points out).

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y You're right: they're like pointer types in many ways(e.g. they can be null and need to be initialized), but not in all ways (eg. they're garbage-collected whereas C++ pointers aren't).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you are asking, exactly, but hopefully the following exposition contains the answer you are looking for.

Variables `ex1`, `ex2`, `ex3` and `exCopy` are all associated with distinct instantiations of `ClassName`.

1. `ex1` points to a heap-allocated instance. Since you never invoke `delete` on it, the instance leaks on exit from the program, which doesn't matter much in this case, but might cause problems if `ClassName` had a non-trivial destructor that had to be called before exit.
2. `ex2` is a default-initialised stack instance, which will have, for all intents an purposes, random values in `age` and `sex`.
3. `ex3` is a member-initialised stack instance.
4. `exCopy` is a copy-constructed stack instance.

Answer (score 2):

> In C++ is there any way to not create
>   object in memory until i need to call
>   it's constructor function?

Yes - create it dynamically:

```
ClassName * p = 0;   // nothing created
...                  // wait a bit
p = new ClassName;   // create instance
...                  // wait a bit
delete p;            // get rid of it
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might want to read about constructors http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html and copy constructors http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/jsmith1/

Answer (score 0):

So what you re asking is: "How can I create an unbound reference in C++?" - Well, you can do that only with pointers, either a plain pointer, or a smart pointer like [Boosts](http://www.boost.org/) [`shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), which should be preferred.

```
{
    tr1::shared_ptr<ClassName> p; // p is a NULL-pointer

    p.reset(new ClassName()); // now a new object is created on the heap and p points to it.
} // no delete needed, shared_ptr counts references and deletes object when no more reference exis
```

Answer (score 0):

> In C++ is there any way to not create object in memory until i need to call it's constructor function?

It's possible to allocate the memory first and then initialize the object later. Is that what you mean?

```
unsigned char memory[sizeof(ClassName)];

// ...

ClassName* p = new(memory) ClassName();
p->print();

// ...

p->~ClassName();
```

(Although I'm pretty sure this is not what you want.)

Comment: This is also very good information for beginners like me. Thank you for your kind and very good answer.

Comment: Note that unless you reinvent `std::vector`, it's pretty unlikely that you'll ever need to know this kind of stuff.